# Concatenating two or more struct-type variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Assuming types of all variables are `struct` and have same `fields` with `concatenatable` size (dimensions). For example:

```
a.x = 1; a.y = 2;
b.x = 10; b.y = 20;
```

With the ordinary concatenation:

```
c = [a; b];
```

returns

```
c(1).x = 1; c(1).y = 2;
c(2).x = 10; c(2).y = 20;
```

What I want is:

```
c.x(1) = 1; c.y(1) = 2;
c.x(2) = 10; c.y(2) = 20;
```

It can be done by:

```
c.x = [a.x; b.x];
c.y = [a.y; b.y;];
```

However, if the variables have lots of fields,

```
a.x1 = 1;
a.x2 = 2;
% Lots of fields here
a.x100 = 100;
```

It's a waste of time to write such a code. Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with `c`? Are you sure it won't be more useful to have `c(1).x` etc? Because then if you want to select a chunk of data you can go `c(5:10)` for example. But your way you'll have to index each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function does what you want, but has no error checking:

```
function C = cat_struct(A, B)
C = struct();
for f = fieldnames(A)'
   C.(f{1}) = [A.(f{1}); B.(f{1})];
end
```

You would use it like this in your code above:

```
c = cat_struct(a, b);
```

Comment: Mendo's solution is helpful, too. But yours is more readable in my opinion, whether it outperforms or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all contents are numbers, or row vectors of the same size, it can be done without loops:

```
f = fieldnames(a);   
t = [f mat2cell(cell2mat([struct2cell(a) struct2cell(b)]), ones(1,numel(f)))].';
c = struct(t{:});
```

The idea here is to generate a cell array of strings (`t`) such that when expanded to a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) (`t{:}`) it will generate the input arguments to `struct` necessary to build `c`.

Example:

```
a.x = [1 1]; a.y = [2 2]; a.z = [3 3];
b.x = [10 100]; b.y = [20 200]; b.z = [30 300];
```

gives

```
c = 

    x: [1 1 10 100]
    y: [2 2 20 200]
    z: [3 3 30 300]
```